# Managed C++ - ignored Header file

Tags: header-files, managed-c++

So I’ve got a HEADER(.h) and a SOURCE(.cpp) file in a Managed C++ VS2010 solution.

My solution builds successfully even though I added garbage to the header.

```
public:
   someConstructor(); // assume the syntax is good here
   asdf // garbage
```

**Why I did this**

My original problem was that I couldn't update my CPP file to add a new constructor. When I added a new constructor to my CPP file, my solution failed to build due to a non-existent overridden member function, i.e. my new constructor. I added garbage to the HEADER file to make sure that VS2010 was actually reading my HEADER file. Obviously it was not.

How can I make sure that VS2010 looks at my HEADER file? It seems to be looking at another HEADER file...

Thanks

Comment: you can use #error to force a build error

Comment: Make sure your build script is pointing towards the H file you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the file(s) in question and open up the properties window (`View->Properties Window`) you can see if your project is looking at the correct file or not. Additionally, if the file is not being included in the build (even though it's in the solution), you can set `Include in Project` to true.

Note that I'm assuming you're using MSBuild. If you're using some other build system, there may be a different procedure for ensuring the build is using the correct header file.

Comment: My "Additional Include Directories" had 50+ folders. What I did was move my local folder, which contained the most up-to-date HEADER file, to the top of the list. thanks, helloworld922